# Strongswan KDF Test

Tags: encryption, key-derivation

How can a KDF implementation for IKEv2 application, specifically in strongswan implementation case can be verified for conformance with NIST SP800-135, please?

SP800-135 KDF recommendation further propose usage of SP800-56C for key extraction and SP800-108 for key expansion. Can we verify extraction and expansion steps implementation separately and what mode e.g counter, feedback, pipeline as per SP800-108, strongswan use for key expansion, please?

NIST Application-Specific Key Derivation Function Validation System (ASKDFVS) discuss KDF test vectors(TV), any idea how to test this TV for strongswan KDF implemenation through some software test suite, Ubuntu Strongswan Cryptographic Module (
140sp2978) mentions of /usr/lib/ipsec/ikev2-kdf-selftest, which I could not find yet.

Comment: Did you read section 4.1.2 in NIST SP800-135?

Comment: @ecdsa Do you want to say that SAHVS and HMACVS are enough to validate a KDF implemenation as SP 800-135 4.1.2 says "The IKEv2 KDFs, which are compliant with SP 800-56C, are approved when used with an approved HMAC function using an approved hash function; see FIPSs 198-1 and 180-3, respectively."  However I have edited and also mentioned ASKDFVS in my query, please.